# Cucumber JSON Formatter for Ruby 2.6 - how to convert from message to json

Tags: json, ruby, cucumber, formatter

Trying to follow the directions from github :https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/json-formatter to create a json formatted result when running cucumber test.

1. first I run
   cucumber --format message ./features/1_VL-2.feature > ./cucumber-report/cucumber-message.bin

(my feature test file called "1_VL-2.feature" on my folder called "feature". I put the output in my folder "cucumber-report" in the file "cucumber-message.bin")

the file cucumber-message.bin then contains the output file of my run.

2. Then trying to convert to json using the description from Github:
   cucumber --format protobuf:cucumber-messages.bin
   cat cucumber-messages.bin | cucumber-json-formatter > cucumber-results.json

get the error that
zsh: exec format error: cucumber-json-formatter
cannot load such file -- protobuf:cucumber_messages.bin
Error creating formatter: protobuf:cucumber-messages.bin (LoadError)

Used this command to the the formatter.curl -Lkfo /usr/local/bin/cucumber-json-formatter 
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/releases/download/cucumber-json-formatter%2Fv5.1.0/cucumber-json-formatter-linux-amd64 
&& chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/cucumber-json-formatter

What am I doing wrong/missing?

Comment: At step 2, what command did you run? You only need to run `cat <file-path> | cucumber-json-formatter > cucumber-results.json`. Based on your post, `<file-path>` should be cucumber-report/cucumber-message.bin`

Comment: Your post uses both singular and plural in the filename. It appears that you create `cucumber-message.bin` and then try to pass `cucumber-messages.bin` to the JSON formatter.

Comment: Hi in step 2 I ran this: cat ./cucumber-report/cucumber-message.bin| cucumber-gherkin-darwin-amd64 > ./cucumber-report/cucumber-message.json. The cucumber-message.json is empty. I have installed the executable referenced on Github relevant for my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I've just updated the [Standalone JSON Formatter documentation](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/json-formatter). If anything is unclear, please raise an issue in that GitHub repo.